# Javascript image zoom (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I go throw the questions here and search the web for image zoom. I found one really nice: http://www.php-help.ro/examples/mootools1.2_image_zoom/ , the problem is that I'm not using MooTools and I can't use it. To find anything similar in pure Javascript or JQuery will be great.

The requirement is that  the zoomed are can be moved on the big one and rectangle on thumbnail will be moving, or by moving the rectangle on thumbnail. It should zoom in after clicking on a big image or some other element (magnifier icon).

**Solution:**

If anyone will be interested, I created a JS just for this purpose. It does not use any JS framework and can be easily integrated into any web site. Still in alpha version and not tested deeply. http://www.marten-online.com/my-projects/pw-zoomer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out: http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom

Comment: I already found that. The problem is that I need to have the moving option on the big image as well. To be honest I'm not so good in JS to add this functionality there.

Comment: oh, I see. Don't have a clue for that functionality.